# Apart from device & vs2012 is there Any Alternative way to test a windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

i am new to windows phone app development , i wanted to know

if is there any other **alternative way** to test a windows phone app apart from testing in a windows phone device and testing vs2012 built in emulator ???

1) The reason i have asked like these that i wanted to know if i can download a windows phone emulator separately and test my app in it.

2)Am i missing any other alternative provided ?

Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

No these are your options. You can start the emulator without VS, and you can deploy apps to it via a command line tool, but you don't get any of these without installing the WP SDK for VS2012. But since this is all free, is that a big deal?

You could submit your app to the store as a beta, and have invited users test your app on their phones.

Comment: First Of All Thanks For Your Reply , i am developing an windows phone 8 app , and giving out a build to tester to test it . The Issues is that i am not able to justify them on my explanation  to the fact that The Testing Enviorment needs a licensed version of vs2012 for testing my app (since we don't have device).

1)Is there any version of vs2012 avaliable which i can use it for more than 1month or 3 months (for a decent amount of time )so that i can use that to be  installed in my testing environment ??
 
I request you that can you help me out on this to me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 2)Is there any way in which i can provide some information to them that this is how it works in microsoft .(any links or doc's).any suggestion from you on these or any workaround  available on this .I request you that can you help me out on this to me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As mentioned you can publish your app as a beta in the phone store. It only takes a few hours and it will only be available to the Live IDs that you specify. They get a private link where they can install the app from. Also the windows phone 8 SDK including VS 2012 Express is FREE for unlimited time, so yes there's a free option. Just install the SDK and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be of use, although it still requires .NET framework and some other dependencies (but I don't think you'll ever get away without using them):

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31861/Windows-Mobile-Development-Without-Visual-Studio